# Error launching Rplidar node

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rplidar, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I am using a RPLidar A1M8 to generate obstacles using move_base and costmap_2d. The problem arrives when I launch rplidar node with the whole system .launch; you can see the include where I call the .launch file of rplidar:

```
  <include file="$(find rplidar_ros)/launch/rplidar.launch" />
```

The next error appears on terminal when I launch it:

```
 [ERROR] [1585914589.956502460]: Error, operation time out. RESULT_OPERATION_TIMEOUT! 
[rplidarNode-20] process has died [pid 14017, exit code 255, cmd /home/sara/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rplidar_ros/rplidarNode __name:=rplidarNode __log:=/home/sara/.ros/log/35a653a0-75a1-11ea-83b0-701ce7079383/rplidarNode-20.log].
log file: /home/sara/.ros/log/35a653a0-75a1-11ea-83b0-701ce7079383/rplidarNode-20*.log
```

I tried to read the .log file, but it doesn't appear on that directory.

By the way, if I launch first the whole system in one terminal and then I launch the rplidar node using other terminal, it works and I can see rplidar working and generating obstacles on rviz.

What can I do to solve the problem and launch rplidar whit the system together?

Thanks in advance.

Best regrets.
Alessandro

EDIT: I solve the problem not launching other node that uses the same usb port of the rplidar, so it was my fault. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348301/error-launching-rplidar-node/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:
Please post your last edit as an answer instead.

And then accept your own answer.

This would convey the fact that your issue was resolved much better than closing a question.

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-04-21**:
Done. Thanks, i am still adapting to ROS Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solve the problem not launching other node that uses the same usb port of the rplidar, so it was my fault. Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2020-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1